# How to serve index.html file with Apollo Server?

Tags: html, heroku, apollo

I have this code in `index.js`:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT).then({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server running at url: ${url}`);
});
```

In local development, when I went to `localhost:5000` on my browser, I could test with the `GraphQL` playground.

Now, I just finished deploying with Heroku. When I go to my URL, I see:
`GET query missing.` I assume this happens because apollo is trying to open the `GraphQL` playground, but it is blocked in production mode.

How can I tell apollo to serve `client/index.html` instead?

Note: I tried putting index.html in the root directory as well, but nothing changed.

I saw in a tutorial video that the answer to this question in express is:

```
app.use(express.static('client'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client','index.html'));
});
```

I don't know how to do this in Apollo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standalone Apollo Server cannot be used for serving static files or exposing other endpoints. If you need this functionality, you need to use an HTTP framework like Express, Hapi or Koa and then [use the appropriate Apollo Server integration](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server#installation-integrations).

Example using Express:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ ... });

const app = express();

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```